# autoComplete completeMethod doesn't work in dialog

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, facelets

I wrote this code:

```
<p:dialog header="Bolletta" width="800" height="600">
      <h:form id="newBillForm" >

            <p:panel header="Dati fiscali">

                <h:panelGrid columns="4">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Cliente *: " for="customer"/>
                    <p:autoComplete id="customer" value="#{billController.customerString}" completeMethod="#{customerController.autoComplete}" required="true"/>

                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>
      </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

If i put the form (and all its content) outside the dialog the completeMethod works fine, but inside the dialog it doesn't work!

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: No, only a form, but this code is in a xhtml page without html tag, only composition (it uses a template). Maybe could be a problem?

Comment: Only if you are nesting forms. For other hints, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked

Comment: Ok with your responses I successfully ovverride the problem, it was response 5, I rendered the dialog, then set null the value renderer, so it couldn't complete the security check. Many Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can have many possible causes, the common ones being nesting `<h:form>` components or using a `rendered` attribute on the input or one of its parents which evaluated `false` during form submit. For a detailed overview of them all, check [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)